# Laravel 4 One To Many with where

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two table PRODUCTS and STOCK.

```
Products
--------
id
name

Stock
------- 
id
products_id
organization
price
```

my code:

```
class ProductsModel extends Eloquent {


protected $table = 'products';

public function stock(){

    return $this->hasMany('StockModel', 'products_id');  

}

class StockModel extends Eloquent {


protected $table = 'stock';

}
```

If I use:

```
$data['products'] = ProductsModel::where('id', $id)->stock()->where('organization', 1)->get();
```

Or

```
$data['products'] = ProductsModel::where('id', $id)->stock->where('organization', 1)->get();
```

get error:

```
Laravel throw error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$stock
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are passing a product id I assume you want just one product instance. You can try this

```
 $product = ProductsModel::find($id);
 $stocks = $product->stock;
```